# How to add a value to an array in a specific location with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
const array = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 }
];
```

and I need to add another entry to it, but it needs to be placeable within any location in the array. So for example:

`array.push({ id: 5, after_id: 2 });` and this should place the new entry between ids `2` and `3`. Is there some standard way of doing this?

Comment: On further reflection I feel that this is _not_ a duplicate of the question specified. That question looks to insert at a given index, this question looks to insert at a position conditional on the contents of the array. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/u9rmsvj4/

Comment: `array.splice(array.findIndex(x => x.id === 2), 0, { id: 5 })` (but note if `{ id: 2 }` is not found in the list, it will be added in the second-to-last position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@p.s.w.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579/p-s-w-g) Has posted what is probably the best solution in a comment already, but I thought I'd post my original solution here as an answer now this is reopened.

You can use `some` to iterate through the array until the correct index is found, then you can slice the array and insert the item at the relevant index:

```js
const arrayTest = [{
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  }
];

const insertAfterId = (array, item, idAfter) => {
  let index = 0;
  array.some((item, i) => {
    index = i + 1;
    return item.id === idAfter
  })

  return [
    ...array.slice(0, index),
    item,
    ...array.slice(index, array.length),
  ];
};

const result = insertAfterId(arrayTest, {
  id: 6
}, 2)
console.dir(result)
```

Comment: Searching for index can be simplified to: `const index = array.find(e => e.id === idAfter).id` and with object deconstruct it can be `const {id: index} = array.find(e => e.id === idAfter)`

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski that syntax is much nicer; that'd imply an extra iteration of the array, though?

Comment: `find` iterates on elements until it finds element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find - same as `some` method

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Sure; but by having _two_ finds surely we're adding an extra iteration?

Comment: there is only one find - just choice how you want to extract `id` - with object deconstruction or not

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski ah I see; but this presumes the items have an id which relates to their index, which we do not know to be the case?

Comment: you are right, there are always some constraints / rules that we have to follow. `arrayTest` can be build by some method - where we will be able to check if id exists or not - if not, developer can throw an error. One of the most important idea is `trash input - trash output` - if we don’t have proper data - how we can manage proper calculation?